# how to write grid view in html table?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I have this grid view and I want to write it as html table but I don't know how
I want to write it in ( table ,thead,  td and tr ) tags . I want to know how to write it in html table

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false" 
                           BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" 
                           ViewStateMode="Enabled" width="713px" CellPadding="3" 
                           HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowSorting="True" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
                           BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="Black"  ShowFooter="True" 
                           GridLines="Vertical" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="20"  onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
                         Height="16px" >
                           <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="الرصيد">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTotal" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="مدين">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="padding:0 0 5px 0"> <asp:Label ID="debit" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("stat_flag").ToString() =="d" ) ? string.Format("{0:0.000}",float.Parse(Eval("stat_amount").ToString())): "0.00" %>'></asp:Label></div>
 <div><asp:Label ID="lblGrandTotal" runat="server" /></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="totallblDebAmount" runat="server" />
     </FooterTemplate>   
        </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="دائن">
            <ItemTemplate>
                  <div style="padding:0 0 5px 0"><asp:Label ID="credit"   
           runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("stat_flag").ToString() =="c" ) ?   
     string.Format("{0:0.000}",float.Parse(Eval("stat_amount").ToString())):   
           "0.00" %>'></asp:Label></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="totallblCredAmount" runat="server" />
     </FooterTemplate>   
        </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField  DataField="stat_desc" 
                                HeaderText="البيان" ItemStyle-Font-   
     Size="Small">
    <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small"></ItemStyle>
                               </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField  DataField="trans_name" 
                             HeaderText=" نوع السند " ItemStyle-Font-  
                  Size="Small">
    <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small"></ItemStyle>
                               </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField  DataField="serial" 
                             HeaderText=" رقم السند " ItemStyle-Font-   
            Size="Small">
         <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small"></ItemStyle>
                               </asp:BoundField>
                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="التاريخ">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="date" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("stat_date" ,"{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" )%>'> ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
   <div style="padding:0 0 5px 0"><asp:Label ID="Label5" Text="اجمالي الصفحة     
  " runat="server" /></div>
     </FooterTemplate>   
        </asp:TemplateField>
                           </Columns>
                             <FooterStyle BackColor="#336699" Font-  
  Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="right" />
                           <RowStyle BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" 
    BorderWidth="1px" />
                           <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DDDDDD" />

                           <HeaderStyle BackColor="#aaaaaa" Font-Bold="True"   
  HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                               VerticalAlign="Middle" ForeColor="Black"    
    BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"/>
                           <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Blue"   
     HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Bold="True" 
                           Font-Underline="False" BorderStyle="Solid" 
    BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#666666" />
                       </asp:GridView>
```

for an example I want to write it in html format like this format

```
   <TABLE CELLPADDING=6>
  <THEAD>
   <TR> <TH>Weekday</TH> <TH>Date</TH> <TH>Manager</TH> <TH>Qty</TH> </TR>
</THEAD>
<TBODY>
 <TR> <TD>Mon</TD> <TD>09/11</TD> <TD>Kelsey</TD>  <TD>639</TD>  </TR>
 <TR> <TD>Tue</TD> <TD>09/12</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>596</TD>  </TR>
 <TR> <TD>Wed</TD> <TD>09/13</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>1135</TD> </TR>
 <TR> <TD>Thu</TD> <TD>09/14</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>1002</TD> </TR>
  <TR> <TD>Fri</TD> <TD>09/15</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>908</TD>  </TR>
   <TR> <TD>Sat</TD> <TD>09/16</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>371</TD>  </TR>
     <TR> <TD>Sun</TD> <TD>09/17</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>272</TD>  </TR>
        </TBODY>
      <TFOOT id="table_footer">
       <TR> <TH ALIGN=LEFT COLSPAN=3>Total</TH> <TH>4923</TH> </TR>
     </TFOOT>
     </TABLE>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could create your GridView, run your project and then right click on the browser screen and Inspect Element. Then, you will see the generated Html code.

Or you can visit this website that has an example that can help you: [Export Gridview To HTML File Using ASP.Net C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/export-gridview-to-html-file-using-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/).